# Sort <tr> tags by they "name" value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I need to sort my `tr` tags by their name attribute value.

Is it possible to use `sort` method in this case?

Or there is another way to do that?

My sort function is on bottom side of code

first I'm taking the input value and appendig it to its parent() name attr. value
after that I need to sort my array of -s alphabetically with name attr. values.

```
$(function() {
  var tableHead =
      "<table>" +
      "<tr>" +
      "<th class='sort'>Id <span class='downArrow'>&darr;</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class='upArrow'>&uarr;</span></th>" +
      "<th id='sort_name'>Name sort</th>" +
      "<th>Surname</th>" +
      "<th>Birthday</th>" +
      "<th>Filter</th>" +
      "<th class='addList'>+</th>" +
      "</tr>" +
      "</table>";

  $('body').html(tableHead);
  var inputName = "<input type='text' class='name' placeholder='First name'>";
  var inputSurname = "<input type='text' class='surname' placeholder='Surname'>";
  var bDayDate = "<input type='date' class='bDayDate' placeholder='Bday'>";
  var addList = $('.addList');
  var downArrow = $(".downArrow");
  var upArrow = $(".upArrow");
  var idNum = 0;
  var arrNum = [];
  var nameArr = [];
  var sortedNameArr = [];
  var sortedArr = [];
  addList.on("click", function() {
    idNum++;
    var tr = $("<tr></tr>");
    for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
      var td = $('<td></td>');
      tr.addClass("" + idNum);
      switch (i) {
        case 1:
          td.addClass("" + idNum);
          td.html(idNum);
          break;
        case 2:
          td.html(inputName);
          break;
        case 3:
          td.html(inputSurname);
          break;
        case 4:
          td.html(bDayDate);
          break;
        case 5:
          td.html(1);
          break;
        case 6:
          td.html("Delete");
          td.addClass('delete');
          break;
        default:
          return console.log("OooPs!!");
      }
      tr.append(td);
    }
    arrNum.push(tr);
    $('table').append(arrNum);

    $('.delete').on("click", function() {
      removeItem(this, arrNum, sortedArr);
    });

    for (var j = arrNum.length; j >= 0; j--) {
      sortedArr.push(arrNum[j]);
    }

    downArrow.on("click", function() {
      $('table').append(sortedArr);
      $('.delete').on("click", function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
      });
    });

    upArrow.on("click", function() {
      $('table').append(arrNum);
    });


    function removeItem(item, arr, sArr) {
      var that = $(item).parent();
      $(item).parent().remove();

      for (var k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
        if (arr[k] && that[0] === arr[k][0]) {
          arr.splice(k, 1);
        } else {
          // console.log(that[0]);
          // console.log(arr[k][0])
        }
      }

      // If you want delete when sort the table
      for (var k = 0; k < sArr.length; k++) {
        if (sArr[k] && that[0] === sArr[k][0]) {
          sArr.splice(k, 1);
        } else {
          // console.log("wrong!!")
        }
      }
    }

  });

  $("#sort_name").on("click", function() {
    var name = $(".name");

    for (var n = 0; n < arrNum.length; n++) {
      var trName = arrNum[n][0];
      $(trName).attr("name", $(name[n]).val());
      nameArr.push(trName);
      // console.log(nameArr[n])
    }
    nameArr.sort();
    for (var n = 0; n < arrNum.length; n++) {
      console.log(nameArr[n])
    }

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to sort your data table manage to call on your array click event like as you follow the function call with the desired field.

```
function sortTable(table, order) {
    var asc   = order === 'asc',
        tbody = table.find('tbody');

    tbody.find('tr').sort(function(a, b) {
        if (asc) {
            return $('td:first', a).text().localeCompare($('td:first', b).text());
        } else {
            return $('td:first', b).text().localeCompare($('td:first', a).text());
        }
    }).appendTo(tbody);
}
could be called on any table like this ther your table may be very by selector.

sortTable($('#mytable'),'asc');
sortTable($('#mytable'),'desc');
```